# How to call an attribute from a class array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to make a method that gets the date and adds onto it an amount of days specified.

At present I cannot call the days specified.

I have a Plant Class that has_many DaysTillSellables, The Period class has_many DaysTillSellable also.

When the user creates a plant they can add a DaysTillSellables and then select a period and then enter an amount of days.

I first need to check to see which period the date is in, then return that period. Currently attempting like so

```
def current_period
    return unless completed_at_week.between?(period.start_week, period.finish_week)
    index_days_till_sellables_on_period_id
  end
```

Then Find the days till sellable that is connected to that period and finally call the days from that

Below is the code for the class I'm trying to call it in

```
 class Potting < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :batch, inverse_of: :pottings
  validates :plant_count, :completed_at, presence: true

  enum germination_result: { light: 0, medium: 1, full: 2 }

  def pottings_completed_at
    "Week #{completed_at.strftime('%U').to_i}/#{completed_at.strftime('%Y').to_i}"
  end

  def completed_at
    super || Time.zone.today
  end

  def completed_at_week
    completed_at.strftime('%U')
  end

  def current_period
    return unless completed_at_week.between?(period.start_week, period.finish_week)
    index_days_till_sellables_on_period_id
  end

  def period_days
    plant.days_till_sellables.find_by(period: :current_period).&current_period.days
  end

  def ready_for_sale
    completed_at + period_days
  end
end
```

I've added more Code below to give better context for classes

```
class DaysTillSellable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :period, inverse_of: :days_till_sellables, foreign_key: :period_id
  belongs_to :plant, inverse_of: :days_till_sellables, foreign_key: :plant_id
  validates :days, presence: true
end
```

.

```
class Period < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :days_till_sellables, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :period
  belongs_to :organization
```

.

```
class Plant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :batches, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :goals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :days_till_sellables, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :plant
  belongs_to :organization
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :days_till_sellables, allow_destroy: true
  validates :genus, :species, :period_id, presence: true
end
```

Comment: My Title may be worded incorrectly, if there is a better way to word it let me know thanks and I will change it

Comment: I can't quite tell what your actual question is. What class method are you trying to call? What do you provide that method as arguments? What is your expected/desired result? What is your current result? Are you getting errors? If so, what errors? Or, are you just getting a non-meaningful return?

Comment: I have a period class that lets the user define periods using a start_week and finish_week from 1-52 (the periods cannot overlap)

 The current_period is suppose to check what period it currently is, by seeing if the completed_at date lays in a period range and if it does it should then return that period_id. 

The next method is suppose to find the days_until_sellable connected with that period_id.

Then I need to call days from that days_until_Sellable and then add that to the completed_at so I can display that date in ready_for_sale.

I'm currently getting naming error

Comment: the error is undefined local variable or method 'plant'. From the, 

 `Def period_days
    plant.days_till_sellable.find_by(period: :current_period).&days
  end`

Comment: I suggest including a little more context in the code listings, like `class Plant < ApplicationRecord`, `class Period < ApplicationRecord`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
class Potting
  belongs_to :plant, through: :batch
  ...
end
```

Comment: I'll try that, Thank you